# What is the difference between a first-person shooter and a third-person shooter?

Tags: first-person-shooter, terminology, third-person-shooter

What is the difference between First person shooter (FPS) and Third person shooter (TPS)? Can a game be both FPS and TPS?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In a [first person shooter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-person_shooter) a player sees through the eyes of his [avatar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avatar_%28computing%29). In a [third person shooter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third-person_shooter) a player sees through a camera over the top of his avatar.

In some games, you play from over the top of the character (3rd Person), and then when you sight down your weapon zoom into the characters eyes (1st Person).  This can also reverse as in Halo where you spend the majority of your time in first person until you enter a vehicle and gain a third person perspective.

First and third person also have some variations:

- In some first person views, you can see your avatar's arms and feet when    you look around, while others do not.
- Two main variations in third person      views exist. The position of the       camera; over head, over the top, over    the shoulder, etc. and the cameras       mobility; stuck in position, or       rotatable around the character.

Answer (score 4):

Games can be both first- and third- person.

In [Halo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halo_(series)) the game is mainly played in first person, but when you drive a vehicle it goes into third person.

In the [Burnout series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnout_(series)) of games the cars can be driven in first or third person mode. (Not strictly a shooter, but the point remains).

[Oddworld: Stranger's Wrath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oddworld:_Stranger's_Wrath) is mainly third person, but you can choose to go into first person at virtually any time.

A lot of Nintendo games (some Mario titles and the Zelda Wii games spring to mind) are basically third person but allow you to switch to first person to look around (but not necessarily move).

Comment: Fallout 3 is another example.

Comment: CoD ModernWarfar2 is another example.

Comment: "Metroid: The Other M" is another, recent example.

Answer (score -3):

In 1st person, you're looking through the eyes of the character as if you *were* the character.

In 3rd person, you're like a drone flying above the character.

*But remember, in both types, you're controlling the character. Except for cutscenes. Usually you can't control those except for RPGs.*

Comment: What exactly does this add that the other answers haven't said?

Comment: I just wanted to simplify.